# My protocol buffer file doesn't find java_package

Tags: java, android, android-studio, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to make a file called game_settings.proto. However, when I use the extension .proto it doesn't make it as a proto file. When I try to choose the file type as protocol buffers it goes well but when I write

```
option java_package = "my package";
```

it gives an error with java_package, same with anything related to Java.
These are dependencies related to the issue:

**Module**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.protobuf'
}

dependencies {   
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.19.4")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.19.4")
}
```

**Project**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.18' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `java_package` that you are providing is not a valid Java package and thus it cannot generate valid Java code In order to solve this you can use something like:

```
option java_package = "my.package";
```

Comment: the problem is not with the package I'm using to declare the value, it's all about java_package itself, I get a red color when writing java_package, same as java_multiple_files @clément-jean

Comment: Could you share the error then? I can better help you if I have this info